# How to check with Liquid if I am in the home page?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I am using Jekyll and I want to have a link to my homepage in all the pages of my site except, of course, in my home page. I thought to put it in the layout.html with a conditional that is true when the actual page is not the home page. Something like this:

```
  {% if site.baseurl != page.url %}
  <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}">Home</a>
  {% endif %}
```

But it is not working. Which is the right way to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you home page url is supposed to always be "/".

You can do :

```
{% if page.url != "/" %}
  <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}">Home</a>
{% endif %}
```